# how may i use template to pass a comparison class?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, operators

I tried to make a comparison class that is `Comp1` and then pass it to the template of `Info1`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

ifstream cin("in.in");
ofstream cout("out.out");

template<typename Compare>
struct Info1 {
    int l;
    int r;
    bool operator<(Info1& a2) const {
        return Compare()(*this,a2);
    }
};

struct Comp1 {
    bool operator()(const Info1& a,const Info1& a2) const {
        return a.r<a2.r;
    }
};


int main() {
    
    vector<Info1<Comp1>> v1;
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile and returns the following error:

```
34:27: error: use of class template 'Info1' requires template arguments; argument deduction not allowed in function prototype
    bool operator()(const Info1& a,const Info1& a2) const {
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Always post error along with your question, always.

Comment: The problem is that `Info1` is a class template not a class-type.

Comment: `Info1` is a template, not a type. You forgot to give it template arguments. But what is your intent here? Why are you doing what you are doing?

Comment: i am trying to give to Info1 a Compare class for knowing if i want to do l<r or l>r in sorting @user17732522

Comment: @adrian See the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75970620/12002570).

Comment: @adrian If you make your class dependent on the `Compare` type, then for each possible choice of `Compare` your class template will generate completely different types. That does not sound like what you want to do. You usually give the comparator to the _algorithm_, e.g. `std::sort`, not the type itself. The type itself usually either has no `operator<` at all or only one `operator<` that provides a default ordering choice.

Comment: Seems like a case of trying to do something simple in an overly complex way.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that `Info1` is a ***class template*** and not a ***class-type***.

Thus to solve this, replace `Info1` with `Info1<T>` as shown below. Also note the added parameter clause for overloaded `operator()`:

```
struct Comp1 {
    //added this parameter clause
    template<typename T>     
    bool operator()(const Info1<T>& a,const Info1<T>& a2) const {
//-----------------------------^^^---------------^^^------------>added this to make it template-id
        return a.r<a2.r;
    }
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9EezY7eKc)

Comment: can i decalre the template before struct Comp1 { ?

Comment: but why did u make a template before the operator , what is that operator taking when is being called ? @Jason

Comment: @adrian  You don't have to make `Comp1` a class template. Since `Info1` is a class template, you must pass some template argument for its corresponding template parameters so that you can get a "class-type".